Ansible compare two JSON responses
I'm using Ansible to call the same administration API on two different servers and then selecting the core details of the applications from the responses using jq.
According to Ansible type_debug the registered variables are of type dict
ok: [localhost] => {
    "node1_applications | type_debug": "dict"
}

ok: [localhost] => {
    "node2_applications | type_debug": "dict"
}

The JSON from the two responses looks like
{
  "Node": "ESB1",
  "AppCoreDetails": [
    {
      "ApplicationName": "APP_Config_V1",
      "LastModified": "2023-08-25 12:23:26"
    },
    {
      "ApplicationName": "APP_Intervals_V1",
      "LastModified": "2022-11-23 14:46:58"
    }
  ]
}

{
  "Node": "ESB2",
  "AppCoreDetails": [
    {
      "ApplicationName": "APP_Config_V1",
      "LastModified": "2023-08-25 12:03:30"
    },
    {
      "ApplicationName": "APP_Intervals_V1",
      "LastModified": "2022-11-23 14:46:58"
    }
  ]
}

Where the LastModified date of the first entry in AppCoreDetails is different and for the second entry it's the same.
I'd like to get the set of objects where the LastMofified dates are different.
{
  "AppCoreDetails": [
    {
      "ApplicationName": "APP_Config_V1",
      "LastModified": "2023-08-25 12:23:26"
    }
  ]
}

BTW I found and tried experimenting with this but failed to convert from simple fields to objects enter link description here

As you've tagged jq, this assumes you want to call jq with the two JSON responses as its input.
You can read in both objects into an array using the --slurp (or -s) flag, and reduce them to the relevant values. Then, use transpose to align the items, and filter for differences using select.
jq -s '
  map(.AppCoreDetails) | transpose
  | {AppCoreDetails: map(select(first != last)[0])}
'

Demo
This assumes that the .ApplicationName values are already aligned for both cases, i.e. the arrays have the same number of items and the names come in the same order. If this is not necessarily the case, specify how to deal with dangling matches. Here's an approach using JOIN and INDEX to find matching .ApplicationName values:
jq -s 'map(.AppCoreDetails) | {AppCoreDetails: [JOIN(
  INDEX(last[]; .ApplicationName); first[]; .ApplicationName; select(first != last)[0]
)]}'

Demo
Given the two sample inputs, both approaches output
{
  "AppCoreDetails": [
    {
      "ApplicationName": "APP_Config_V1",
      "LastModified": "2023-08-25 12:23:26"
    }
  ]
}



Concatenate the lists and convert the attributes LastModified to lists

  nodes: "{{ (node1_applications.AppCoreDetails +
              node2_applications.AppCoreDetails) |
              json_query('[].{ApplicationName: ApplicationName,
                              LastModified: [LastModified]}') }}"

gives
  nodes:
    - ApplicationName: APP_Config_V1
      LastModified: ['2023-08-25 12:23:26']
    - ApplicationName: APP_Intervals_V1
      LastModified: ['2022-11-23 14:46:58']
    - ApplicationName: APP_Config_V1
      LastModified: ['2023-08-25 12:03:30']
    - ApplicationName: APP_Intervals_V1
      LastModified: ['2022-11-23 14:46:58']


Append the lists by the index ApplicationName

  nodes_merge: "{{ [nodes, []] |
                   community.general.lists_mergeby('ApplicationName',
                                                   list_merge='append') }}"

gives
  nodes_merge:
    - ApplicationName: APP_Config_V1
      LastModified: ['2023-08-25 12:23:26', '2023-08-25 12:03:30']
    - ApplicationName: APP_Intervals_V1
      LastModified: ['2022-11-23 14:46:58']


If there are more items on a list take the first one

  AppCoreDetails_dict: |
    {
    {% for i in nodes_merge %}
    {% if i.LastModified | length > 1 %}
    "{{ i.ApplicationName }}": "{{ i.LastModified | first }}",
    {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    }

gives
  AppCoreDetails_dict:
    APP_Config_V1: '2023-08-25 12:23:26'


Convert the dictionary to a list

  AppCoreDetails: "{{ AppCoreDetails_dict | dict2items(key_name='ApplicationName',
                                                       value_name='LastModified') }}"

gives
  AppCoreDetails:
    [
        {
            "ApplicationName": "APP_Config_V1",
            "LastModified": "2023-08-25 12:23:26"
        }
    ]



Example of a complete playbook for testing
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    node1_applications:
      AppCoreDetails:
        - ApplicationName: APP_Config_V1
          LastModified: '2023-08-25 12:23:26'
        - ApplicationName: APP_Intervals_V1
          LastModified: '2022-11-23 14:46:58'
      Node: ESB1

    node2_applications:
      AppCoreDetails:
        - ApplicationName: APP_Config_V1
          LastModified: '2023-08-25 12:03:30'
        - ApplicationName: APP_Intervals_V1
          LastModified: '2022-11-23 14:46:58'
      Node: ESB2

    nodes: "{{ (node1_applications.AppCoreDetails +
                node2_applications.AppCoreDetails) |
                json_query('[].{ApplicationName: ApplicationName,
                                LastModified: [LastModified]}') }}"
    nodes_merge: "{{ [nodes, []] |
                     community.general.lists_mergeby('ApplicationName',
                                                     list_merge='append') }}"
    AppCoreDetails_dict: |
      {
      {% for i in nodes_merge %}
      {% if i.LastModified | length > 1 %}
      "{{ i.ApplicationName }}": "{{ i.LastModified | first }}",
      {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}
      }
    AppCoreDetails: "{{ AppCoreDetails_dict | dict2items(key_name='ApplicationName',
                                                         value_name='LastModified') }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: nodes | to_yaml

    - debug:
        var: nodes_merge | to_yaml

    - debug:
        var: AppCoreDetails_dict

    - debug:
        var: AppCoreDetails

    - debug:
        msg: |
          AppCoreDetails:
            {{ AppCoreDetails | to_nice_json }}



Whilst I accepted @pmf's response I wish I could accept two answers. This one certainly taught me a lot about Ansible and manipulating dicts and list. My thanks for all your work.

To better understand @pmf's answer I cloned the content in the link to the second Demo and broke the jq command map(.AppCoreDetails) | {AppCoreDetails: [JOIN( INDEX(last[]; .ApplicationName); first[]; .ApplicationName; select(first != last)[0] )]} into it's component parts, remember to set the -s option in the new playground when you do so.
I also read through Understanding jq's SQL style operators JOIN and INDEX
Starting with map(.AppCoreDetails) we get:
[
  [
    {
      "ApplicationName": "APP_Config_V1",
      "LastModified": "2023-08-25 12:23:26"
    },
    {
      "ApplicationName": "APP_Intervals_V1",
      "LastModified": "2022-11-23 14:46:58"
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "ApplicationName": "APP_Config_V1",
      "LastModified": "2023-08-25 12:03:30"
    },
    {
      "ApplicationName": "APP_Intervals_V1",
      "LastModified": "2022-11-23 14:46:58"
    }
  ]
]

Piping the map to last map(.AppCoreDetails) | last gives:
[
  {
    "ApplicationName": "APP_Config_V1",
    "LastModified": "2023-08-25 12:03:30"
  },
  {
    "ApplicationName": "APP_Intervals_V1",
    "LastModified": "2022-11-23 14:46:58"
  }
]

Adding the brackets map(.AppCoreDetails) | last[] gives us:
{
  "ApplicationName": "APP_Config_V1",
  "LastModified": "2023-08-25 12:03:30"
}
{
  "ApplicationName": "APP_Intervals_V1",
  "LastModified": "2022-11-23 14:46:58"
}

Which provides the content for the first, stream, parameter of the INDEX function map(.AppCoreDetails) | INDEX(last[]; .ApplicationName) giving:
{
  "APP_Config_V1": {
    "ApplicationName": "APP_Config_V1",
    "LastModified": "2023-08-25 12:03:30"
  },
  "APP_Intervals_V1": {
    "ApplicationName": "APP_Intervals_V1",
    "LastModified": "2022-11-23 14:46:58"
  }
}

The INDEX is then fed into the JOIN
map(.AppCoreDetails) | JOIN( INDEX(last[]; .ApplicationName); first[]; .ApplicationName; select(first != last)[0] ) giving:
{
  "ApplicationName": "APP_Config_V1",
  "LastModified": "2023-08-25 12:23:26"
}

And so we get to the full command map(.AppCoreDetails) | {AppCoreDetails: [JOIN( INDEX(last[]; .ApplicationName); first[]; .ApplicationName; select(first != last)[0] )]} where the wrapper text gets added to provide the desired answer:
{
  "AppCoreDetails": [
    {
      "ApplicationName": "APP_Config_V1",
      "LastModified": "2023-08-25 12:23:26"
    }
  ]
}

Other experiments included

Adding an extra entry in the first array which then appears in the output because it just doesn't exist in the second array.
Swapping first[] and last[] in the command. Which demonstrates the behaviour is order dependent. Think WRT(With Respect To)
Updating the select to compare fields rather than the entire object select(first.LastModified != last.LastModified)[0])

Finally a big thank you to @pmf for his help.
